# Problema el insertar registros en una tabla temporal en Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Buenos días estoy tratando de crear una tabla temporal el firebird 2.5. Necesito que sea una tabla temporal, porque solo voy a cargar códigos que voy a usar en un procedimiento y luego no me van a servir para mas nada. En resumen, creo la tabla temporal pero al momento de insertar algun registro me salta un error de que la tabla no existe. Les dejo el codigo que estoy usando:

```
create global temporary table TEMPCODES
(
  codigo varchar(13)
)
on commit delete rows;

insert into TEMPCODES values('20-04422898-0');

--Aca van N inserts. Esta n depende de un ciclo for que los va a insertar.
```

Yo a modo de prueba intento crear la tabla e insertar 1 solo registro, pero al momento de ejecutar la linea del insert me arroja el siguiente error:

> can't format message 13:796 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg
> not found. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -204. Table unknown.
> TEMPCODES. At line 1, column 13.

Siempre trabaje con SQL Server y Oracle, la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal o si me falta alguna sentencia. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Viendo la documentación, no encuentro nada incorrecto. ¿Has intentado hacer `commit` entre la creación de la tabla y el primer `insert`?

Comment: Hice el commit pero cuando tiro el select ahora falla y en el select me dice que no ve la tabla.

Comment: ¿cómo así?, no entiendo No hay ningún select en tu pregunta..

Comment: O sea hago el commit y ya no tira problema al insertar, pero si al hacer un select

Comment: sospecho que estás haciendo otro commit entre el `insert` y el `select`, y la creación de la tabla tiene la cláusula `on commit delete rows`.